# Android ImageAdapter of GridView shows the same (doubled) images

Tags: android, image, gridview

My problem is simple: when i click to show GridView (everything is good), then I press back and again click on GridView. Then there are doubled images in GridView. For example, if first time there was 5 photo in GridView, second time there are 10 photos. I think the problem is in my ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (view == null) {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.squareimageview, null, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item) items.get(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
            name.setText(item.name);
        } else {
            v = view;
            System.out.println("Cia");
        }



        return v;

    }

}
```

GridView:

```
public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

...

```
items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
        items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
        items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
        items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
        items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    int drawable;
    String text;

    public int getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public Item(String name, String text, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
        this.drawable = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem is not here..  Problem is here you can this BaseAdapter..

Comment: Okay, now look to my code

Comment: do you clearing your list (Items.clear)!!!!??

Comment: where you set your adapter or notify your adapter?

Comment: No. Where can I put it? In else?

Comment: where you are seeting your adapter in which method OnCreate or OnResume or any other methods post your other code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably not finishing the activity when you go back, so the gridview is never killed and gets again the same batch of images (at onresume() callback i believe?).

If that is the case, make sure you either finish() the activity overriding onBackPressed() or recreating the ListView every onResume() call:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
```

Then add the data.

However to identify the problem we need more of your code.

**<<<<< EDIT: >>>>>**

Ok this is the problem:

```
public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Just remove the static modifier:

```
public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Having a static modifier makes that list persistant between your activity. That means you keep adding items onto it while it never gets re-created/ cleared.

Or else you can simply clear the list every time you are about to add the item batch:

```
items.clear();
items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
        items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
        items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
        items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
        items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are getting double images cause you are not clearing the `ArrayList` you use as data holder.

you have some solution:

- you clear the ArrayList just before you add the items

  ```
  items.clear()
  items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
  items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
  items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
  items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
  items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));
  ImageAdapter imaadpter=new ImangeAdapter(this,items);
  gridView.setAdapter(imaadpter);
  ```
- you check if there are items in the array before adding them

  ```
  if( items.isEmpty() ) {
      items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
      items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
      items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
      items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
      items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));
  }
  ImageAdapter imaadpter=new ImangeAdapter(this,items);
  gridView.setAdapter(imaadpter);
  ```
- when you go back you call `items.clear()`, then you won't get double items for sure.

**NB:** there is also an other pretty big bug in your code, you don't notice it cause you have not enought items to require scroll or reuse of the grid view item.

in your getView method you got to set the values outside the if-else statemant so that when you reuse a View you will update it's content

```
   @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v;
    ImageView picture;
    TextView name;

    if (view == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.squareimageview, null, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);            
    } else {
        v = view;
        System.out.println("Cia");
    }

    Item item = (Item) items.get(i);

    picture.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
    name.setText(item.name);


    return v;

}
```